# Passing Dynamically Typed Object as Props with Next.js + TypeScript

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm making an app using Next.js + TypeScript.
I'm getting the error `Type 'VoidFunctionComponent<ShirtDetailProps>' is missing the following properties` when passing props to a component. How can I resolve it?

One thing I should mention is that the type of the object changes depending on its category.
`details` should be `Details`, but `category_details` within `Details` could be either `Shirt` or `Bag` depending on the `category_name`.

```json
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "details": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "category_name": "shirt",
                "category_detail": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "size": "small",
                    "color": "white"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "category_name": "bag",
                "category_detail": {
                    "id": 13,
                    "width": 30,
                    "height": 15
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "category_name": "shirt",
                "category_detail": {
                    "id": 45,
                    "size": "large",
                    "color": "pink"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

```js
export interface Box {
  id: number;
  details: Details[];
}

export interface Details {
  id: number;
  category_name: string;
  category_detail: CategoryDetail[];
}

export interface Shirt {
  id: number;
  size: string;
  color: string;
}

export interface Bag {
  id: number;
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

export type CategoryDetail = Shirt | Bag;
```

That being said, where I'm getting the error is below:

```js
const Foo: NextPage = () => {
  const { box } = useFetchBox();

  return (
    <div>
      {box.details.map((detail) => (
        {detail.category_name === "shirt" && <ShirtDetail categroy_detail={detail.category_detail as unknown as typeof Shirt} />} // error: Type 'VoidFunctionComponent<ShirtDetailProps>' is missing the following properties from type 'ShirtDetail': id, size, color
        {detail.category_name === "bag" && <BagDetail categroy_detail={detail.category_detail as unknown as typeof Bag} />} // error: Type 'VoidFunctionComponent<BagDetailProps>' is missing the following properties from type 'BagDetail': id, width, height
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

`ShirtDetail` simply looks like:

```js
interface ShirtDetailProps {
  category_detail: Shirt;
}

const ShirtDetail: React.VFC<ShirtDetailProps> = ({
  category_detail,
}) => {
  return (
    // some code
  );
};

export default ShirtDetail;
```

Before I came across this error, I tried the following steps:

1. `categroy_detail={detail.category_detail as Shirt}` gave me `'Shirt' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Shirt'?`
2. Changed it to `category_detail={detail.category_detail as typeof Shirt}` as suggested, and it gave me `Conversion of type 'CategoryDetail[]' to type 'VFC<ShirtDetailProps>' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.`
3. Changed it to `category_detail={detail.category_detail as unknown as typeof Shirt}` as suggested, and it gave me `Type 'VoidFunctionComponent<ShirtDetailProps>' is missing the following properties from type 'Shirt': id, size, color`
4. No clue how to fix it.

Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example, perhaps in the TypeScript Playground. Otherwise it is difficult to follow what is happening and try different approaches. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73245839/10421404 I have resolved my own question... I will keep that in mind for the next time. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake that I had `Shirt` component defined in my project. TypeScript was confused with the `Shirt` type and the `Shirt` component.
I changed the name of the `Shirt` component and the error disappeared with `categroy_detail={detail.category_detail as unknown as Shirt`.